# How Server.CreateObject(progId) in ASP works?

Tags: c#, .net, asp-classic, interop

I'm migrating some old classic ASP code to ASP.Net. One of the pages creates an instance of a COM component with:

```
obj = Server.CreateObject("myProgId").
```

In the C# version I'm trying to do the same using something like this:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("myProgId"));
```

The question is if both lines of code get an instance of the same class considering that the same `ProgID` could be registered more than once with a different `ClassID`.

**Second question:** 
Is there any way to know which `ClassID` is using `Server.CreateObject()` to create the instance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) sysinternals tool I could figure out which file handles where open when creating the instance.